# remove trailing slashes from .html but add trailing slash to everything else

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess task I can't accomplish. I need all pages ending in .html/ redirect to .html . All other pages must end with a trailing slash. And finally, these rules must not affect /adminstrator/ page. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution myself. Thanks :)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html/ http://somedomain.com/$1\.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Couldn't do it before, because needed to exclude the /administrator/ rule twice